# Neo4jRestClient: How to Add Indexes After the Nodes and Connections Have Already Been Created?

Tags: .net, neo4j

I am quite new with neo4j and currently using Neo4jRestNet Client. I created a small network for purpose of learning:

```
private static void GenerateNetwork()
        {
            var rootNode = Node.GetRootNode();

            // Create a User Node with Properties
            var prop = new Properties();
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Name.ToString(), "Madeline J. Parnell");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Age.ToString(), "25");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.LivesIn.ToString(), "LA");

            var nodeUserWithName1 = Node.CreateNode(NodeType.Person.ToString(), prop);

            prop = new Properties();
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Name.ToString(), "Jack S. Waldrop");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Age.ToString(), "28");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.LivesIn.ToString(), "San Francisco");

            var nodeUserWithName2 = Node.CreateNode(NodeType.Person.ToString(), prop);

            prop = new Properties();
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Name.ToString(), "Willis O. Hicks");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Age.ToString(), "33");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.LivesIn.ToString(), "Ann Arbor");

            var nodeUserWithName3 = Node.CreateNode(NodeType.Person.ToString(), prop);

            prop = new Properties();
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Name.ToString(), "Leroy P. Wagner");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Age.ToString(), "40");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.LivesIn.ToString(), "Hattiesburg");

            var nodeUserWithName4 = Node.CreateNode(NodeType.Person.ToString(), prop);

            prop = new Properties();
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Name.ToString(), "Nancy J. Rose");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Age.ToString(), "25");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.LivesIn.ToString(), "Cornish");

            var nodeUserWithName5 = Node.CreateNode(NodeType.Person.ToString(), prop);

            prop = new Properties();
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Name.ToString(), "Sally G. Gee");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Age.ToString(), "48");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.LivesIn.ToString(), "Charlestown");

            var nodeUserWithName6 = Node.CreateNode(NodeType.Person.ToString(), prop);

            prop = new Properties();
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Name.ToString(), "Blanche T. Perez");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Age.ToString(), "35");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.LivesIn.ToString(), "Philadelphia");

            var nodeUserWithName7 = Node.CreateNode(NodeType.Person.ToString(), prop);

            prop = new Properties();
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Name.ToString(), "Robert S. Johnston");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.Age.ToString(), "22");
            prop.SetProperty(NodeProperty.LivesIn.ToString(), "Lancaster");

            var nodeUserWithName8 = Node.CreateNode(NodeType.Person.ToString(), prop);

            // Create Relationships to Nodes
            rootNode.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName1, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            rootNode.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName2, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            rootNode.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName3, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            rootNode.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName4, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            rootNode.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName5, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            rootNode.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName6, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            rootNode.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName7, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            rootNode.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName8, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());

            // Create Relationship with Properties
            //var relProp = new Properties();
            //relProp.SetProperty(RelationshipProperty.Name.ToString(), "MyRelationship");
            //relProp.SetProperty("CustomRelProp", "CustomPropValue");

            nodeUserWithName1.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName2, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName1.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName3, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName2.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName3, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName5.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName6, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName6.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName8, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName7.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName1, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName7.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName1, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName7.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName3, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName7.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName4, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName7.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName5, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName7.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName6, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());
            nodeUserWithName7.CreateRelationshipTo(nodeUserWithName8, RelationshipType.Knows.ToString());

        }
```

I tried to find a methods to create indexes, which would be equivalent to the following java methods:

IndexManager index = graphDb.index();
Index people = index.forNodes( "people" );
RelationshipIndex roles = index.forRelationships( "roles" );

and add it to the person, created with GenerateNetwork() method, which is done in java with following method:

```
people.add( nodeInstance, "valueName", reeves.getProperty( "valueName" ) );
```

Anyway so far I haven't found the way to deal with indexes using Neo4jRestClient. Does anyone know how to check for existing indexes and assign nodes to indexes using Neo4jRestClient?

I would be very thankful if anyone shared an example.

Answer (score 0):

You add Nodes/Relationships to indexes by using the `AddToIndex` method. For example:

```
var node1 = Node.CreateNode();
node1.AddToIndex("nodes", "name", "jack");
```

or you could use the static function on `Node`:

```
Node.AddToIndex(node1, "nodes", "name", "jack");
```

where `"nodes"` is the name of the index and `"name"`/`"jack"` is the key/value pair.

If you pass an `Enum` for the value parameter it will use the value in the properties collection on the node.

Note: I just pushed new code as of 6/6/2012 and you should try to start using it. It now supports batch processing of commands and I will be updating the API to support the cypher mutating commands very shortly. I will also be updating the docs asap as they are currently out of date.

hth.

Comment: Jack, thanks for the answer. I can't run the new version. The old one ran without problem, but the new one is throwing exception at line  var rootNode = Node.GetRootNode();

Comment: Could you give me your email address or contact in order to talk about the solution?

Comment: Niko, the GetRootNode method will throw an error if the root node has been deleted from the graph. here is a link to a discussion on neo4j.org that talks about this (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/Sb2ANlJtLDY ). My personal take on this; i do not like the idea of RootNode.  i prefer to crate a node as a root to my graph because of the issues raised in the discussion on neo4j.  if you would like you can open issues on https://github.com/SepiaGroup/Neo4jRestNet thanks.